# fstream .open() Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, ifstream, getopenfilename

I am trying to figure out this and its bugging me for a long now.

when i type:

`inFile.open("C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\text.txt", ios::in | ios:: binary);`

it works just fine.
But when i do something like this.

`string garbage = "\\";`

```
        srcLoc = ofn.lpstrFile; // this is: C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\text.txt

        // This for loop inserts "\\"
        for(int i = 0; i < srcLoc.length(); i++)
        {
            switch(srcLoc[i])
            {
            case '\\':
                srcLoc.insert(i, garbage);
                i++;
                break;
            }
        }
       // Now string srcLoc looks like: C:\\Users\Mark\\Desktop\\text.txt
        inFile.open(srcLoc.c_str(), ios::in | ios:: binary);
       // But it wont work

        if(inFile)
        {
            while(!inFile.eof())
            {
                getline(inFile, tekst);
                SendMessage(hTextBox, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)tekst.c_str());
                SendMessage(hTextBox, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, (LPARAM)"\r\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(0, srcLoc.c_str(), "Could not load", MB_ICONWARNING | MB_OK);
        }
        inFile.close();
```

What i get is MessageBox "Could not load" working at least :) Anyone know what i am missing?

Comment: You should only need to double the backslashes in literal strings, not in variables that are already alright.

Comment: When you're hard coding a file path in a literal string just use a `/`, it works on Windows too and then you don't need to escape all the backslashes.

Answer (score 6):

You need to double the backslashes when you're using them in a string in source code. The compiler will convert each double-backslash in your source code to a single source code in the string used by the program.  When you're reading a string coming in at run time, you do *not* need to double the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Now string srcLoc looks like: C:\\Users\Mark\\Desktop\\text.txt
```

This is **not** what the string should look like in the debugger (or anywhere else during runtime). This is only the way a string with backslashes is represented in source code.

Your loop attempting to add an extra `'\'` doesn't work either, because the compiler will remove the single backslashes and replace them with the value corresponding to the escape sequence, if any. For example the sequence `'\t'` is replaced by a tab character.

You can solve your problems by using an alternate path separator instead

```
"C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/text.txt"
```

this works for Windows as well, and not just for Linux.

Comment: But can i feed inFile.open() with "C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/text.txt" ? seem it is not working.

Comment: Yes, that should work (if that is the actual path to an existing file).